# array of string values not getting populated in the option list in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, erb, html-select

The array of strings values are not getting populated in the option list. I am not sure where I might have gone wrong. Here goes the code that I am stuck at.

```
<html>
Status : <select id = 'status_update'>
             <%=
 array = ["Submitted", "Replied", "Answered", "Assigned", "Started", "Closed","Reopened",  "Canceled"]
          status = '';
           for index in 0 .. (array.size-1)
        status << "<option value = '#{puts (eval(array[index].inspect))}'>'#{(array[index].inspect)}'</option>"
                  end
              %>
  </select>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby instead of

```
for i in 0...ary.size do
  ary[i]
end
```

you can use [`Array#each`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-each):

```
ary.each do |item|
  item
end
```

This is how I would do it in ERB (more or less):

```
<% %w(Submitted Replied Answered Assigned Started Closed Canceled).each do |status| %>
  <option value="<%= status %>"><%= status %></option>
<% end %>
```

Output:

```
<option value="Submitted">Submitted</option>
<option value="Replied">Replied</option>
<option value="Answered">Answered</option>
<option value="Assigned">Assigned</option>
<option value="Started">Started</option>
<option value="Closed">Closed</option>
<option value="Canceled">Canceled</option>
```

Explanation:

- `%w(Submitted Replied Answered Assigned Started Closed Canceled)` creates the array
- `<% ary.each do |status| %> ... <% end %>` is a loop that's executed for each element, the variable `status` refers to the current element within the loop
- `<option value="<%= status %>"><%= status %></option>` is the output for each element, `<%= status %>` is replaced with the corresponding element (`Submitted`, `Replied`, ...)